# Determine the closest available cloud function region from client

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

I have a firebase cloud function deployed in multiple regions. I need to call the function from a client and the [firebase docs state](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations#client-side_location_selection_for_callable_functions) that I must specify the region to call from the client. I'm trying to figure out how to always call the endpoint closest to the client.

What would be the best way to do this with JS on web clients? Is there a way of using the browser IP or timezone to guess the region and map that to EU vs US?

Thanks,

Cloud function definition:

```
export const admin =  functions
    .region("us-central1", "europe-west2")
    .https.onCall(app);
```

Client region selection (need to make this dynamic)

```
var functions = firebase.app().functions('europe-west2');
```

Comment: Ideally, you have to deploy a HTTPS load balancer in front of your cloud functions. But with firebase, i don't know

Comment: jjdav, please let me know if the below information was helpful.

Comment: I came across a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75112435/13130697) and posted a snippet that finds nearest region based on timezone. Is that what you are looking for?